# After upgrading the preview of text messages on my lockscreen feature disappeared

Tags: updates, sms, lock-screens

I have a HTC One Mini and recently upgraded from Android version 4.2 to 4.3,. Everything went fine, but I noticed when people were sending me messages that I couldn't see a preview of them or who sent them on my lock screen. I went into Settings and Personalized settings and my lock screen feature has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The settings have moved to the "Security" list, rather than the "Personalisation" list, but I've been unable to see previews on my lockscreen since the update even with these settings. Others that I know have experienced the same issue.
HTC just recommend a factory reset... -_-